# PHP Laravel PDOException General error referencing column and referenced column in a foreign key constraint are incompatible

Tags: php, laravel, terminal

I am currently doing migrations in Laravel via the Terminal, and have these two errors when attempting to use php artisan migrate; I will print errors below:

```html
Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'room_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'contacts_room_id_foreign' are incompatible.")
      /Users/shaquilenoor/Desktop/chatapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      /Users/shaquilenoor/Desktop/chatapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458
```

Based on the code contained within the Exception Trace, the issue seems to be within the code below:

```html
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateContactsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user1_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user2_id');
            $table->integer('room_id')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms');
            $table->foreign('user1_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('user2_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('contacts');
    }
}
```

any ideas on how I can resolve?

Comment: ```$table->id(); //UNSIGNED BIG INTEGER``` so              ```$table->unsignedBigInteger('room_id')
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you're on **Laravel 5.8** new migration changed to big increments, so for fixining refrencing error just change **integer** to **bigInteger**, for example:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Will changed to:

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 5):

Either change original migration 
from

> bigIncrements()

to just

> increments();

---

**Or** In your foreign key column do

> bigInteger()

instead of

> integer()

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why is this needed?

Answer (score 4):

The foreign key must be the same as the referencing id,
and hence change

```
$table->integer('room_id')->unique();
```

to

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('room_id')->unique();
```

and it does the trick.

PS: you'll get another error

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view
> already exists: 1050 Table...

just delete the table and run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 3):

In ***Laravel 6.0***, migrations are as same as ***@Payam Khaninejad*** mentioned. i.e.

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
```

I am updating that for ***Laravel 6.0*** because, I was following an old tutorial that has shown the same error.

Answer (score 1):

### users table

```
$table->increments('id');
```

### contacts table

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();  //adding unsigned() here, will fix the error
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 8.x, change `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();` to:
`$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');`  because this is compatible with the `id()` data type.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `room_id` should be unsigned. Try this:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user1_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user2_id');
            $table->integer('room_id')->unique()->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms');
            $table->foreign('user1_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('user2_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also in laravel 7.x you may have to change:

```php
$table->increments('id'); // UNSIGNED INTEGER
// to 
$table->id(); // UNSIGNED BIGINT
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - how does this change relate to the given error message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is an issue with tables that were migrated in older versions. Ive got the same problem and in my case I used two differents types of declaration for each foreign keys. "integer" and "unsignedInteger"

```
        $table->integer('webcam_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
     

        $table->foreign('webcam_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('webcam');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem during a migration to create a table with a foreign key constraint.  I found that it had to due with the collation used on the table.  Our DB schema is loaded with a schema file, and that has the table collation set to `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.  It looks like Laravel uses `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` by default.

I resolved the problem by setting the collation for the table during creation with `$table->collation = 'YOUR_COLLATION_VALUE'`

Answer (score 0):

in your room migration, change the id as such

```
$table->id();
```

it will automatically create bigInteger with name 'id'

then in your contact migration, use

```
$table->bigInteger('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms');
```

same goes to the other foreign keys, just follow above code.

well at least this syntax works on laravel 8

Answer (score -3):

This is due to the foreign keys being set before the rooms table being created. you can fix this by doing the following.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateContactsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user1_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user2_id');
            $table->integer('room_id')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('room_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user1_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user2_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms');
            $table->foreign('user1_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('user2_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::dropIfExists('contacts');
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}
```